# Sending tcp/ip packet( or MQTT packet) from ARM cortex-m4 microcontroller UART to telit modem

Tags: arm, mqtt, gsm, at-command, uart

I am currently using NXP micro-controller which is ARM-Cortex-m4.

I want to use UART of micro-controller to connect to UART of Telit Modem.
Are there any helpful links where I can get source code or links for sending tcp/ip packet from microcontroller to modem using UART as communication channel.

Can I send directly MQTT packet from UART to Telit modem?(Another sub question)

What protocol should I follow?

Comment: requests for links to off site resources are off topic for Stack Overflow. Please read the doc on what sort of questions to ask: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1):

Telit modems provide a wide set of AT commands for TCP/UDP, so you can send through them any data based on protocol that is conveyed through TCP/UDP, and this includes MQTT.

Explaining all sockets-related AT commands would be too wide. I can suggest starting with the following command (you can find them in AT command user guide):

- AT#SD
- AT#SH
- AT#SCFG
- All commands related to PDP context activation, such as +CGDCONT, #SGACT and so on.